# Download large volumes from S3 to Local Machine? - s3distcp

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hdfs, distcp

Currently using `distcp` is slow, taking up to 4:16 minutes to copy 1 hour's worth of logs, while a custom function wrote by me only takes 16 seconds. Given that Amazon provides `s3distcp` examples involving logs, I thought to give this a go and test its performance.

I know this is possible with `distcp` but is it possible to use `s3distcp` on the local machine to copy large volumes of data (potentially 100gb+) onto a hfs cluster on the local machine without the use of EMR?

Amazon and subsequent tutorials and articles only reference `s3distcp` abilities as a step in EMR..

Comment: This is unrelated to your commands, but Amazon has globus support in beta.  Globus is really nice for copying large amounts of data and you might want to check it out.

Comment: Oh nice, is it optimized for a few, large files, or a large number of small files? @Mark

Comment: I think it works well for both.  It does a good job of resuming huge transfers that sometimes become broken for whatever reason.  It does everything in the background so you don't have to babysit it.

Comment: Nice, thanks @Mark. Right now the problem is downloading a bunch of small files, which is slow with `distcp` but since `s3distcp` seems to be optimized for logs, I thought I would give it a go. A custom function created by me is taking roughly 16 seconds for 1 hour's worth of logs while `distcp` takes 4:16 seconds...

Comment: Both, distcp and s3distcp, are MapReduce jobs that run on Hadoop, What do you mean with "Local Machine"? HDFS is a distributed file system, then the concept of "local Machine" doesn't really exist. No one is optimized for small or large files but HDFS doesn't work very well with a huge amount of small files, its strong is work with a very large splittable files.